# How to manipulate the mouse position reliably using Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, automation

I have automated a series of clicks in a process using Python with the mouse.position(x,y) function on python. It has been helpful and now I'm looking to improve that.

The downside to the application is that the clicks are made on a browser. Whenever the browser size change and the buttons move, the mouse clicks will no longer be accurate. Is there a way where I can make the mouse positioning more accurate? Alternatively, is it possible for applications opened by my automation algorithm to be located in a fix position on the screen and have a fixed window size so that the buttons do not move out of the preset coordinates?

Thanks.

Comment: if its a browser you should really be using selenium or something similar ... there are also tool like sikuli or something that could help you ... but this question is probably gonna get nuked here

Comment: [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser

Comment: this may help ... https://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/?platform=linux